# How to visit on multiple variants with restricted to same type

Tags: c++, variant, visitor-pattern, unreachable-code

I have a question about using a generic visitor with exclusion of non-equal types. Suppose I have the following:

```cpp
using StorageT = std::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double>>;

StorageT process_data(const StorageT &lhs, const StorageT &rhs) {
    return std::visit([&](auto &&l, auto &&r){
        return kernel(l, r);   // some templated kernel 
    },
    lhs, rhs);
}
```

Externally, I verify that the underlying stored type for variants `lhs` and `rhs` match. I'd like to write a generic visitor, without code being generated for all combinations of `lhs` and `rhs` where the underlying variant types are not the same.

As it stands, all combinations of the two underlying variant types are generated.
Inside the lambda, I could write

```cpp
if constexpr(std::is_same_v<Tl, TR>) {
    return kernel( ... );
} else {
    // Do nothing
    // static_assert(false);
    // Throw exception
}
```

Since all combinations of `lhs` and `rhs` are generated, the above code either a) complains about no return on the mismatch of types, b) fails due to the static assert, or c) generated a code path for an exception which will never be thrown (due to an external check of the types).

What is the best way to avoid code generation for all cases where the underlying types for `lhs` does not equal `rhs`?

Comment: `What is the best way to avoid code generation` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/unreachable ?

Comment: @KamilCuk Ah yes that slipped my mind, and does appear to work. Would this be the best approach, or is this code smell which suggests that I should consider a redesign?

Comment: fwiw, a) is trivial to bypass. You know that the branch is not taken so simply place a `return kernel( ... );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just visit one of the types and use that to determine the other type:

```
StorageT process_data(const StorageT &lhs, const StorageT &rhs) {
    return std::visit([&](auto &&l){
        auto &r = std::get<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(l)>>(rhs);
        return kernel(l, r); 
    },
    lhs);
}
```

Comment: I think this makes sense to me; rather than visit on all possible underlying types, visit on all possible valid types (assuming external equality checks have been done), and thus I can be sure that code generation does not occur without relying on the compiler optimizing it out. Thanks!

Comment: @JakeTuero: I realized later that if you always check that the types match before calling `process_data()` you can eliminate a bunch more code by using `auto &r = *std::get_if<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(l)>>(&rhs);`.  That eliminates an unnecessary type check and exception throwing code which you know will never run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::unreachable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/unreachable) (defined in the `<utility>` header).
From the documentation:

> **Invokes undefined behavior**. An implementation may use this to optimize
> impossible code branches away (typically, in optimized builds) or to
> trap them to prevent further execution (typically, in debug builds).

*(emphasys is mine)*

Since the compiler can assume undefined behavior will never happen, it is a classic case for optimizing away the piece of code that you never expect to be needed.

So your code can be:

```
#include <utility>   // for std::unreachable

// ..

if constexpr(std::is_same_v<Tl, TR>) {
    return kernel( /*...*/ );
} else {
    std::unreachable();
}
```

Comment: This does not completely eliminate the unused combinations: https://godbolt.org/z/d6eExW75h - look at the bottom there are 4 cases of __gen_vtable.

Comment: According to my understanding of the documentation it's a classic case for optimization, so it it's strange that gcc didn't take advatage of that. Am I wrong ?

Comment: You're right that this kind of thing can be a use case for std::unreachable().  But relying on the optimizer does require that you inspect the generated code, and in this case it falls short of optimal.